# How do I get "et al." to appear in italics when using \textcite or \citeauthor with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, formatting, chemstyle

I'm using `biblatex` with the `chem-rsc` package option. I sometimes make use of the  `\textcite{<key>}` or `\citeauthor{<key>}` commands to put the authors' name into text. When there are many, it writes "Bloke et al.", but I would like to make it put the "et al." in italics.

I'm sure there are some hacky ways of doing this by rewriting parts of commands. I'm hoping that there is some fairly straight forward and robust method for it though.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

"et al." corresponds to the localization key `andothers`. In most styles it is set by the generic bibliography macro `name:andothers`. You can redefine this macro to wrap `\bibstring{andothers}` in `\emph`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{companion} \citeauthor{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Audrey, this solution works. Might I ask though to any biblatex developers that might have seen this, that it would be nice to have some option to do this without redefining the `name:andothers` macro.

Comment: @aghsmith You can submit [feature requests here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=browse&group_id=244752&atid=1126006), though I have my doubts such an option would be incorporated. This is a style issue and the existing style can easily be adapted to meet your needs.

Comment: @Audrey: A simple: \bibstring[\emph]{andothers} is enough.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Ah, the wrapper argument. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @aghsmith Just an addendum. egreg's new `xpatch` package will make it much easier to make small changes like these to both bibliography macros and drivers. Feel free to accept lockstep's answer instead.

Answer (score 24):

This is another case where egreg's [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package comes in handy. Instead of copy-pasting the whole content of the `name:andothers` bibmacro, one may selectively apply changes (as suggested by Marco Daniel):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=chem-rsc]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{companion} \citeauthor{companion}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or with the `\xpatchbibmacro` provided by the `xpatch` package, of course, soon to be also on TeX Live. :)

Comment: @egreg One of my aims in answering this question is to make Audrey aware of your great solution. :-)

Comment: @lockstep: Please see my comment under the previous answer. The `wrapper` of `bibstring` must be command like `emph`.

Comment: @lockstep +1 Yes, I upvoted that answer (and your use case with the year format) other day. I considered using the patch, but went with a redefinition instead.

Comment: @egreg Great! Could bibliography drivers be patched? Some definitions are quite long and a pain to modify when you're just wanting to make a small change.

Comment: @Audrey Any command defined with `\newbibmacro` can be patched. The package provides also `\xshowbibmacro` to see the definition.

Comment: @egreg I don't think I was clear. I'll head over to chat.

Comment: Maybe you would like to update your solution to use the `xpatch` package, so it is shorter.

Comment: @moewe Done. (some filler text)

Comment: Very nice indeed.

Comment: Is it possible that years later something changed in `biblatex` sources so that this solution does not work anymore? it doesn't work for me anymore.

Answer (score 17):

Another way to achieve this is as follows:

```
\usepackage[maxnames=6,minnames=3]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
```

You actually have control over the whole text and its styling, and you can control for different languages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10):

I was using `\etal` in the document text (not in the bibliography) and I had to use a different style where `\etal` was not defined.

So I've just created the command:

```
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `biblatex` v3.17 (2022-01-25) or above you can use bibstring formatting sets to typeset "et al." in italics.

Bibstring formatting sets allow us to apply additional formatting to sets of bibstrings. We could, for example, give a set of Latin terms and use italics for those. The bibstring sets are usually defined per language inside `\DefineBibliographyExtras`, since their logic depends on the actual translation.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \DeclareBibstringSet{latin}{andothers,ibidem}%
  \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{latin}{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}
\UndefineBibliographyExtras{british}{%
  \UndeclareBibstringSet{latin}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Italic "et al." in "Lorem (Aksın et al. 2006)"]

Some more background and discussions can be found in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1028, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/1027, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/899.