# How to change the format of the "and" bibstring using xpatch?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, xpatch

When using `biblatex`'s `textcite` command with a two-authored reference I want the "and" between them to be in italics. I managed to get the same for the "et al." `\bibstring` using the following code snippet, based on the `xpatch` package (and thanks to [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40999/18674)):

```
\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
    \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
    \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}
```

However, just replacing `name:andothers` with `name:and` or `and` does not achieve that, as can be seen from the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
    author = {Uthor, A. and Uthor, B.},
    title = {And and Or or Or and And},
    year = {2014}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%%%% This does not work %%%%
\xpatchbibmacro{name:and}{%
    \bibstring{and}%
}{%
    \bibstring[\emph]{and}%
}{}{}
%%%% %%%% %%%%
\begin{document}
This is how it looks like: \textcite{test} but the "and" should be italic, as in "Uthor \emph{and} Uthor"
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I could not find, where in the `biblatex` sources the `and` `\bibstring` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a `name:andothers` defined. However, this may help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring[\emph]{and}\space}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
[...]
```