# Use \xpatchbibmacro in ExplClass

Tags: documentclass-writing, xpatch

I need to print the `et al.` output from `\textcite{}` (`biblatex` Pkg) in italics. As stated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40999/46653) this can be achieved by using `\xpatchbibmacro{}` from the `xpatch`  package.

Having this command either in the document itself or in a `cls` file providing a `latex2e` `class` works without problems. Though, when using the command in an `ExplClass` the patching stops working.

Is there anything one can do to make the patching work in an `ExplClass`, or should this be reported as bug to the `xpatch` maintainer(s)?

---

## MWE

### Compilable `tex` file

```
\documentclass{TestExplClass}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{companion} \citeauthor{companion}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### The called `cls` file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{ expl3 , xpatch }
\ProvidesExplClass
  {TestExplClass}
  {2017/10/22}
  {0.1}
  {Class that is having problems}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{\bibstring{andothers}}{\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}{}{}

\endinput
```

Comment: Why are you using `Expl` class here? Which `expl3` content is there? I can see none directly -- it is hidden of course in `expl3` and `xpatch`. I can imagine that you get in trouble with the catcode regime of `expl3` here that lets `\xpatchbibmacro` fail...

Comment: The MWE is just an excerpt from a much larger `cls` file with several hundred lines, just, as needed for an MWE I cut it down to the minimum where it stops working, in this is the (already) use of the `Expl` class itself.

Comment: A MWE has a compilable example document at least, not just the class.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer is such a failure possible without any error or warning in the log? -- Compilable file comes in a minute.

Comment: I don't know much about `\xpatchbibmacro`, but I really feel it is connected to `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` - regime. If you try `\AtBeginDocument{\xpatchbibmacro{...}}` it works as well as with by adding `\ExplSyntaxOff` just before `\xpatchbibmacro` explicitly (which is not meant this way by the developing team of `expl3`, however. I think the `:` in `name:andothers` confuses `expl3` possibly

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Amazing, that's already the answer I guess. Thanks a lot! Do you think this should be reported to `xparse`, or is usage of `AtBeginDocument{...}` a (let's say) normal thing? Or rather a problem with `expl3`?

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument` is pretty widely used. At lot of LaTeX code relies on the those `\@begindocumenthook` contents added with `\AtBeginDocument`, e.g. `hyperref` doing a lot of redefinitions of `\section`, `\label` etc. with  `\AtBeginDocument`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to prevent such problems with `expl3` is to jump out of the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` regime, by shifting the `\xpatchbibmacro` statement into `\AtBeginDocument`, keeping the `:` in `name:another` 'alive' in the sense of traditional `TeX/LaTeX`

The patching should occur on document level anyway, so `\AtBeginDocument` is the right place to do so, in my point of view.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{ expl3 , xpatch }
\ProvidesExplClass
  {TestExplClass}
  {2017/10/22}
  {0.1}
  {Class that is having problems}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{report}

\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{\bibstring{andothers}}{\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
}
\endinput
```

MWE - code (unchanged from O.P.)

```
\documentclass{TestExplClass}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{companion} \citeauthor{companion}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]