# BibTeX style with "et al" in italic

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

My supervisor wants me to use an `apalike` bibliography style.
However, he would like the "et al." mention to be in italic.

When more than 2 authors are cited, LaTeX writes something like:

> [John et al., 2020]

and my supervisor would like something like

> [John *et al.*, 2020].

Do you know any bibstyle which does such a thing? Or a way in which I could implement it myself?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have tagged the question with `biblatex`, but the question body mentions `apalike`, which is a BibTeX style (no `la`) and the title also says "BibTeX". Are you open for a `biblatex` solution (bearing in mind that you can not use `.bst` files like `apalike` with `biblatex` and that there is no style that gives exactly the same output as `apalike` out of the box)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm speaking of bibTeX, not biblaTeX but if a solution exist only on bibLaTeX, I'm ready to learn it.

Comment: If you look in the `apalike.bst` file (http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/bibtex/apalike.bst), you will find (EDIT) 3 occurrence(s) of `et al`.  You can create a new bib style by making a copy of that file, renaming it and editing  that single occurrence to be italic.  Then have your document reference the *new* bibliography style.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Actually, there are three instances of `" et~al."` in the file. :-)

Comment: @Mico Ah ha.  Some are "et al" some are "et~al"

Comment: With `biblatex` it is extremely easy to make the "et al." appear in italics, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40798/35864. But as I mentioned before `biblatex` will not easily give you exactly the same output as `apalike`, so if your professor insists on that, a better choice is probably to modify a copy of `apalike.bst` (as suggested by Steven B. Segletes).

Comment: so I should replace "et al" by "\emph{et al}" ?. @moewe he is flexible with apa style, he just wants the "et al" in italics

Comment: Yes, I think that should work.  Note @Mico 's comment that there are in fact three occurrences, some with some without a hard space separator

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - The lone instance of `"et al"` (without the `~` character) in the bst file is somewhat tricky, and it should *not* be changed to `"\emph{et~al}"`. The reason I call it "tricky" is that it's used exclusively for sorting purposes. Hence my recommendation *not* to modify that string...

Comment: @Mico That's why you got my upvote!  Great discernment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `apalike-etal-in-italics.bst`.  (Don't edit the original copy of `apalike.bst` directly.) Naturally, you're free to choose a different file name.
- Open the file `apalike-etal-in-italics.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Replace all three instances of the string `" et~al."` with `" \textit{et~al.}"`. In my copy of the file, the instances occur on lines 224, 848, and 850.
- Do *not* modify the lone instance of `"et al"` on line 927. It's used for sorting purposes only, and it is used only for entries for which the list of authors was truncated and replaced by the keyword "and others". Observe that the string `"et al"` doesn't contain a tie (tilde) and doesn't end in a `.` ("period", aka "full stop").
- Save the file `apalike-etal-in-italics.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your mail tex file, replace

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apalike-etal-in-italics}
  ```

  and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!