# Specific Square Bracket Citation using Natbib

Tags: citing, natbib

I want to use natbib package. This is the requirement of the journal citations:

> 1. References should be cited in text in square brackets by giving the last name of the author and the date of publication, e.g. [Wong (1989)]. For papers by two authors, the last names are joined by “and” e.g. [Al-Hussaini and Abd-El-Hakim (1989)].

With natbib, two authors will be joined using '&', how to change that?

> 2.References are given in brackets unless the author’s name is part of the sentence,
> e.g. “the a-model [Gupta et al. (1997)]” but “according to Gupta et al. [1997].”

I cannot use the `square` option in natbib as it will change all other citation of year to square. But I want to use `[year]` in text citation only. How to set that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you use at present.

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting the provided answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward to achieve your formatting objective by creating variants of the `\citet` and `\citep` commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{wong:89,author="Wong",title="{AA}",year=1989}
@misc{aa:89,author="Al-Hussaini and Abd-El-Hakim",title="{BB}",year=1989}
@misc{gupta:97,author={Gupta and X and Y},title="{CC}",year=1997}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} % or some other suitable bib style
%% created "bracketed" variants of \citep and \citet
\newcommand\brcitep[1]{[\citet{#1}]}
\newcommand\brcitet[1]{\citeauthor{#1} [\citeyear{#1}]}

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\brcitep{wong:89}

\brcitep{aa:89}

\brcitep{gupta:97}

\dots\ according to \brcitet{gupta:97} \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really help.

Comment: how to change the et al in italics?  any idea?

Comment: @una - For a substantially new question, please post a new query. That way, many more potential readers will see you query, and some will hopefully be in a position to provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, for your advice. I found the solutions from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532367/bibtex-style-with-et-al-in-italic .