# Biblatex \citeauthor style (number of authors and remove et al. underlining)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using biblatex to get the `\citeauthor` command. However, I wish to edit the output of that command and have not yet found how to achieve what I want.

I'm importing biblatex as:

```
\usepackage[
    style=ieee,
    isbn = false,
    url = false,
]{biblatex}
```

And have this following reference:

```
@inproceedings{raster-to-vector,
    author = {Liu, Chen and Wu, Jiajun and Kohli, Pushmeet and Furukawa, Yasutaka},
    title = {Raster-To-Vector: Revisiting Floorplan Transformation},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Computer Vision (ICCV)},
    month = {Oct},
    year = {2017}
}
```

When I use `\citeauthor{raster-to-vector}`, I wished to get a simple "Liu et al." (first author followed by et al.).
However, this is the current output:

[image: citation]

It contains the last name of the first three authors and only then the `et al.`. Also, I'd like to remove the underline that is currently shown. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have fixed the number of authors in the in-text citations by setting `mincitenames=1` and `maxcitenames=1`, still could not get rid of the underline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. I changed `mincitenames` and `maxcitenames` for changing the number of authors, and used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251936/271037) to remove the underline.
The final commands are as follows:

```
\usepackage[
    style=ieee,
    isbn = false,
    url = false,
    mincitenames = 1,
    maxcitenames = 2,
]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
```