# Italicize "et al." while using style=authoryear with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, authoryear

LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{cotton}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output is:

> Read Cotton et al. (1999).
>
> #### References
>
> Cotton, Frank Albert et al. (1999). *Advanced inorganic chemistry.* 6th ed. Chich- ester: Wiley.

I need to italicize *et al.* in citation and references. So I did this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

Read \textcite{cotton}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now output is:

> Read Cotton *et al.* (1999).
>
> #### References
>
> Cotton, Frank Albert *et al.* (1999). *Advanced inorganic chemistry.* 6th ed. Chich- ester: Wiley.

Is `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}` a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does the job. Conceptually, I'm not too fond of adding formatting markup like `\em` and friends into bibstrings, but in this case it could be argued that italicising is part of the orthography.

Personally, I prefer the solution using bibstring formatting sets explained in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/644877/35864) to [How do I get "et al." to appear in italics when using \textcite or \citeauthor with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40798/35864), but of course purely code-wise it is longer than just changing the bibstring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \DeclareBibstringSet{latin}{andothers,ibidem}%
  \DeclareBibstringSetFormat{latin}{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}
\UndefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \UndeclareBibstringSet{latin}%
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Read \textcite{cotton}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Read Cotton et al. (1999).]

This also italicises the Latin "ibidem".